# How to write js file using php?

Tags: php, javascript

How can I edit a javascript file using php. I want to change the file path dynamiacally is it possible to do with php. Please help me?

test.js is my file. this is for display images on frontend

from admin panel me create one folder named flower. then I will create one flower named folder 
and copy this test.js to that folder. after that I have to edit the file path of test.js file. how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to edit the content of file or want to move from one path to another?

Comment: Please can you give a practical example of what exactly you're trying to do and explain what do you want to obtain?

Comment: Can you make the question more clear so that you can get what are you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP file will get executed on the server and an HTML file (usually) will be sent to the client. This file will contain a `<script type="text/javascript">...` line somewhere if you're including a javascript file. You can rewrite this line in your PHP file to make it pick up the file from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, if you mean changing the `<script src="...">` in your HTML.

Anyway, it's like

```
<script src=<?php echo '"' . $path . '"'?>></script>
```